# obj in sequence: comparing with 'is' rather than '=='

Tags: python, python-2.7

In a program I have something like this going on:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, index, other_attribute)
        self.index = index #is of type int
        self.other_attribute  = other_attribute

    # I know this is being taken out of python 3,
    # but I haven't converted it to using __eq__ etc.
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        if self.index < other.index:
            return -1
        if self.index == other.index:
            return 0
        if self.index > other.index:
            return -1
```

here's the problem

```
#here are some objects
a = MyClass(1, something)
b = MyClass(1, something_else)
c = MyClass(2, something_more)

ary = [a,c]

if b not in ary:
    ary.append(b)
```

This will not append b because their indices are equal, but they are still different instances. This is `b == a` is true, but `b is a` is false. I would like to test for membership by address, not by equivalence. Is there a way to have the `in` and `not in` operators use `is` and not `==`? Are there other operators/algorithms that would solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to test membership by address, you could use this `any`/`is` combo:

```
if not any(b is x for x in ary):
    ary.append(b)
```

If you are stuck on using the `in` syntax, you could define your own list object and implement a [`__contains__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) method that compares with `is` rather than `==`.